# Extract date from file path in java

Tags: java, regex, date, filepath

I have a root folder which contains subfolders all of the form

```
somepath/yyyy/mm (also somepath\yyyy\mm)
```

and another root folder which contains subfolders all of the form

```
somepath/yyyy/mm/dd (also somepath\yyyy\mm\dd)
```

where yyyy is a year like 1955, mm is a month like 09 and dd is a day like 01.

I would like for each subfolder to extract the yyyy, mm and dd using java.

Is there a regex that does it taking into account the specific file separator?
Or what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: is there an own foider 1995? with subfolders of 09 or is the name of the folder "1995/09/01" ?

Comment: lets say the root folder is c:\root or /home/root. Inside there will be subfolders 1995/09/01, ... (or 1995/09, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the current level you are in:
level can be year, month or day (you can use any enum or int)
- Start with year level.
- read the all filenames into an map of

```
HashMap <Integer, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
```

which is a map of `<Year, Map<Month>, List<Days>`

- read all the filenames of the years folder, and store that 
  to the map
- change to month level: read all value from the map which are subfolders, 
  and read and store all month values.

You can solve this recursively.

Comment: Yes thats it. Thank you also for the recursive idea.

Answer (score 2):

You should use FilenameFilter:

```
String path = "C:/tmp";
File dir = new File(path);

        FilenameFilter yearFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file, String fileName) {
                if(file.isDirectory()) {
                    if(fileName.matches("^\\d{4}$")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            };

        String[] names = dir.list(yearFilter);
```

Create similar filters for month and days. And then iterate for each e.g.: path+"/"+names[i]. All data would be great to save in `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

To get values from path in String, you can use regex:

```
(?<year>\d{4})[\\/](?<month>\d{2})(?:[\\/](?<day>\d{2}))?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eP6qW5/1)

which will capture values in form yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy/mm (\ or / as separator) in groups with names: year, month, day. Then you cen get them with method group(group) of Matcher class. Or you can take whole mathed string (like "2004/09/01") and process it another way.

Comment: Each path contains only a date component. so "/" are path separators. So a folder 2010 with sub folders 09 with sub folder 15